# from_avro with schemaRegistryAddr is not mapping "value" to it's respective schema

Tags: python, pyspark, databricks, avro

I am using from_avro in databricks to convert values from kafka streams.
This is the code that I am using:

```
.withColumn("record",from_avro(fn.col("value"),
  schemaRegistryAddress=dbutils.secrets.get(scope=secrets_scope, 
   key="schema_repo"), 
   subject=topic_name))
```

I have a job that runs continuously. Sometimes schema will change and data will flow with new schema. I found that from_avro is using only one schema and not matching latest records with latest schema. I restarted the job and set the flag of `startingOffsets` to `earliest` to get the old data. I found that from_avro is mapping new schema for old values.(Ideally it should check schema_id first and then map respective value with respective schema).

Am I missing something? I tried reading documentation but could not find anything.